# Sending an Array to Controls

Tags: c#, arrays, controls, output

So, I'm a student beginning to learn C# in school and one of my current projects has come to involve outputting an expandable, class method-bound array to controls on a form, and I've hit a confusing snag. I've set the proper access modifiers to public, I've successfully used this formatting for an expandable array before, and my program shows no build errors, but the data won't output.

I can see my logic error being a part of my array declaration, which in past permutations seemed like it wasn't expanding, though my current strategy, which calls the `Expand()` method, directly increasing my index `noobIdentifier`, which is a universal variabel within the class, outside of the actual method.

```
//Create Form Instance
AttendanceReport report = new AttendanceReport();

//Expand Array
Expand();

//Create Array
int SIZE = noobIdentifier + 1;
Noob[] info = new Noob[SIZE];

//Assign Data to Array
info[noobIdentifier].s_class = Class;
info[noobIdentifier].s_name = Name;
info[noobIdentifier].s_id = ID;
info[noobIdentifier].s_password = Password;
info[noobIdentifier].s_formerDistrict = District;
info[noobIdentifier].s_grade = Grade;
info[noobIdentifier].s_country = Country;
info[noobIdentifier].index = SIZE;
```

It could also be a part of my actual output block in the same method. I have considered trying to use a For loop instead of a Foreach in my Listbox output, though the latter seemed more concise.

```
//Ouput Gateway
if (output == true)
{
    //Temp Holder
    int i;

    //Output items to Attendance Report Listbox
    foreach (Noob noob in info)
    {
        //Send Index to string
        string indexer = noob.index.ToString();

        //Convert to Int
        i = int.Parse(indexer);

        report.newStudentSelectionBox.Items.Add(i);
    }
}

//Output Text Gateway
if (textOutput > 0)
{
    //Declare Index
    int n = textOutput - 1;

    report.classOutput.Text = info[n].s_class;
    report.nameOutput.Text = info[n].s_name;
    report.idOutput.Text = info[n].s_id.ToString();
    report.gradeOutput.Text = info[n].s_grade.ToString();
    report.districtOutput.Text = info[n].s_formerDistrict;
    report.countryOutput.Text = info[n].s_country;
}
```

Both `output` and `textOutput` are the method inputs, with `textOutput` being declared as an `int` so that it can be used as a direct reference to array placements.

Comment: You are not adding the items to the listbox, you are only adding the index `i`. If the `Noob` class overrides `ToString()`, you can display the array items directly without loop with: `report.newStudentSelectionBox.DataSource = info;`. Or without the need to override `ToString()` by setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. What does this mysterious method `Expand` do? Debug to see what happens. [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Not sure what `Expand()` does, but you're adding just the i variable which will be an integer to that ListBox.  Assuming that `noob.index` is already an integer (which it better be or you'll throw an exception while parsing it's string representation), then there is no need to convert it to a string and then back to an int.  Unless the assignment specifically says that you need to manually add your values in code then you should look in to data binding.

Comment: If manual binding is a requirement though, then override the `ToString` method for your `Noob` class and return the property that you would like to see displayed in the `ListBox` and then just add the `Noob` instances directly to the `ListBox`'s `Items` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

In `Noob` class:

```
public class Noob
{
   //Your Definition...
   public override string ToString() => this.Name;
}
```

Modify loop like:

```
//Output items to Attendance Report Listbox
foreach (Noob noob in info)
{
    report.newStudentSelectionBox.Items.Add(noob);
}
```